# Solving Run time error 91 in my code

Tags: vba, ms-access

I try to match a pattern in a text using Regularexpressions, but I get this Run time error. Could you please help me to solve this problem?

Run time error 91:
Object variable or with block Variable not Set

code:

```
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim ts As TextStream
Dim Name As String
Dim regexp As Object
Dim colregmatch As MatchCollection

 Name = "D:/test_DC.txt"
 Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(Name, ForReading)
 Do While Not ts.AtEndOfStream
 regexp.Pattern = "KENNFELD\s+([ 0-9]*)" //Error
  Set colregmatch = regexp.Execute(searchstr)
  If colregmatch.Count <> 0 Then
        For Each Match In colregmatch
           MsgBox Match
        Next Match
 End If
 Loop
```

**UPDATE:**

```
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim ts As TextStream
Dim Name As String
Dim regx As New regexp
Dim colregmatch As MatchCollection

 Name = "D:/test_DC.txt"
 'Set regexp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
 Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(Name, ForReading)
 Do While Not ts.AtEndOfStream
  regx.Pattern = "KENNFELD\s+([ 0-9]*)"
  Set colregmatch = regx.Execute(searchstr)
  If colregmatch.Count <> 0 Then
        For Each Match In colregmatch
           MsgBox Match
        Next Match
 End If
 Loop
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't created a regex object (only declared an object placeholder):

(This is VBScript not VBA; VBScript's regex has the methods you are using in your posted code)

```
Dim regexp as New RegExp
```

If you really want this in VBA (but you would have to change the methods called in your code):

```
Dim regexp As Object
Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

... Use regexp


Set regexp = Nothing
```

Refs:

[Microsoft Beefs Up VBScript with Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx)

[Regex match in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13554692/regex-match-in-vba-excel)

Comment: If I change my code, I see no errors but the program goes to Not responding situation and I must restart it. I have updated the  code above

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to check is whether you have `Option Explicit` defined at the top of your VBA Module. I suspect that you don't, because there are a couple of undeclared variables in your code. Using `Option Explicit` will prevent LOTS of headaches arising from undeclared variables, typos, etc..

Next, your code is entering an endless loop because you are looping on `While Not ts.AtEndOfStream` but you never actually *read* anything from the TextStream, so you'll never get to the end.

The following version of your code seems to work for me:

```
Sub regexpTest()
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim ts As TextStream, searchstr As String
Dim Name As String
Dim regx As New regexp
Dim colregmatch As MatchCollection, matchItem As match

Name = "D:\test_DC.txt"
'' Set regexp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(Name, ForReading)
Do While Not ts.AtEndOfStream
    searchstr = ts.ReadLine
    regx.Pattern = "KENNFELD\s+([ 0-9]*)"
    Set colregmatch = regx.Execute(searchstr)
    If colregmatch.Count <> 0 Then
        For Each matchItem In colregmatch
            MsgBox matchItem
        Next matchItem
        Set matchItem = Nothing
    End If
    Set colregmatch = Nothing
Loop
'' clean up
ts.Close
Set ts = Nothing
Set regx = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```